# fixed header and footer in dompdf

Tags: css, codeigniter, dompdf

I have a table of data which dynamically producing, and I converted the html page into pdf using dom pdf.I want to add header and footer on each page. but the problem is when the data is large the footer is not stable, and also the the header and footer is not repeating on each page.

```
     <div class="conainer-fluid">
                        <div class="row0">
                        <div class="header"><img src="<?php echo base_url()?>public/images/alhamed.jpg" style="width: 700px;"></div>

                        </div>
 <div class="card-body">


                    <div class="table-responsive-sm">

                        <table class="table table-striped">
                           <thead class="thead-default">

                                                        <tr>
                                                            <th class="text-center"> # </th>
                                                            <th> Product </th>

                                                        </tr>
                                                        </thead>
                                                        <tbody>
                                                            <?php
                                                            for($j=0;$j<40;$j++)
                                                            {
                                                            ?>
                                                            <tr>
                                                              <td>haii</td>
                                                            </tr>

                                                        <?php
                                                            if($i<$count)
                                                            {
                                                             $i++;
                                                            }
                                                         }
                                                        ?>
                                                        </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>

      <div class="conainer-fluid">
                    <div class="row1">
<div class="footer"><img src="<?php echo base_url()?>public/images/footer.jpg" style="width: 700px; margin-bottom: 150px;"></div>
```

- css

  table td{page-break-after: always;}
         .header { position: fixed; }
         .row1{position: fixed;background-color: lightblue;}

how can i make the header and footer repeating on each page of pdf according to the data ?

Comment: Please fix your code formatting,  and how many rows do you intend to show per page?

Comment: as much as possible, if the limit exceeds the balance should show in next page with header and footer